# How to abort Jenkins pipeline stage after failed tests

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline, bdd

I use **Jenkins** to run the custom BDD framework. It is currently setup to run daily and the whole test suite runs every time. Now I am trying to setup my pipeline (using declarative pipeline) the way so I will have few phases of the daily runs: Pre-check, Main run, Report sending, etc. My goal is to have the **pre-check stage** that will show that few key features working and after that - have the main suite run. And I came across a problem when I need to **abort the next stage** if my **pre-check scenarios will fail**. I haven't found a solution so far, so I would appreciate if someone could share an idea.
Problem is that executing shell command is always successful, the test suite doesn't fail, its just the test scenarios may fail. So depending on that I need to **proceed/abort next stage**.
This is how my pipeline file look now:

```
...

pipeline {
   agent {
    ...
   }
   environment {
    ...
   }
   options {
    ...
   }
   triggers {
    ...
   }
   parameters {
    ...
   }
   stages {
    stage('Setup Environment') {
        steps {
            script {
                ...
            }
        ...
        }
    }

    stage('Phase 1: Pre-run Check') {
        steps {
            sh "bash -c '. ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm; bin/hal test ${hal_env} ${params.Browser} --tags @phase-1-check'"
        }
    }
    stage('Test On Firefox') {
        parallel {
            stage('Runner A') {
                steps {
                    sh "bash -c '. ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm; bin/hal test ${hal_env} ${params.Browser} --tags @phase-2-test --retry 2 --parallel [1,4] || true'"
                }
            }
            ...
        }
    }
    stage('Send Daily results') {
        steps {
            ...
        }
    }
   }
   post {
    always {
        ...
    }
   }
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that your test-suite is returning a non-zero exit code when tests fail?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make my test-suite to return exit code, but instead I used '| tee output' command to output the log to a file which I could afterwards read (with awk command) and look for failures in the log. 
So the problem is solved and here is my solution:
'''

```
def phase1_status;
...
stage('Phase 1: Pre-run Check') {
            steps {
                sh "bash -c '<Start Command> | tee hal_output'"
                script {
                  phase1_status = sh( returnStatus: true, script: "awk \'/scenario.*failed/ {exit 1}\' hal_output")
                }
            }
}
stage('Test On Firefox') {
            when {
              equals expected: 0, actual: phase1_status
            }
...
```

'''